# How to show only 2nd featured img on home/blog

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to show only 2nd featured image on home/blog.

Plugin is this: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/dynamic-featured-image

Developer told me that I can do something like this:

```
<?php
if( class_exists('Dynamic_Featured_Image') ) {
     global $dynamic_featured_image;
     $featured_images = $dynamic_featured_image->get_featured_images( get_the_ID() );
    //If you want to display all featured images you can loop through the image to display them as required
    foreach( $featured_images as $image ) {
        echo "<a href='{$image['full']}'>";
            echo "<img src='{$image['thumb']}' alt='Dynamic Featured Image' />";
        echo "</a>";
    }

    //if you only want to show 2nd featured image you can do
    if (isset($featured_images[0])) {
        $image = $featured_images[0];
        echo "<a href='{$image['full']}'>";
            echo "<img src='{$image['thumb']}' alt='Dynamic Featured Image' />";
        echo "</a>";
    }

 }
```

Can someone help me to do this. Do i need to add something in functions.php or how? thanks in advance.

Check also this link, my discussion with developer: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-show-only-2nd-featured-img-on-homeblog?replies=4

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This need to be placed into your template.

```
if( class_exists('Dynamic_Featured_Image') ) {
//if you only want to show 2nd featured image you can do
    if (isset($featured_images[1])) {
        $image = $featured_images[1];
        echo "<a href='{$image['full']}'>";
            echo "<img src='{$image['thumb']}' alt='Dynamic Featured Image' />";
        echo "</a>";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now Im not using child theme. As I understand, I just added this code to functions.php but still no result. Do I need to add something to other file like module-6.php wich I am using. Theme is [link](http://themeforest.net/item/newsmag-news-magazine-newspaper/9512331)

Comment: I tried that with no result just code appears in place for image. This is my template where I need to put it. this is the link : http://www.textsnip.com/jngte7 . thanks in advance.